# catch the shell script execution log through ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, imagemagick

I tried to convert a large number of pdf files to images using the `convert` command. I read all files from my folder, which have pdf and html files, but html files have the extension ".pdf". I received those files from a remote server, so I can't check which files are pdf files and which are not. I used this code:

```
%x[convert "#{source_path}" "#{destination_path}".jpg]
```

When the `source_path` points to an html file, the following error is returned:

> GPL Ghostscript 8.60: Unrecoverable
>   error, exit code 1 convert: Postscript
>   delegate failed `/home/20100.pdf':  @
>   error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/645. convert:
>   missing an image filename`
>   /home/test/20100-1.jpg' @
>   error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2970.
>   Success Error: /syntaxerror in -file-
>   Operand stack:
>
> Execution stack:    %interp_exit
>   .runexec2   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1889   1
>   3   %oparray_pop   1888   1   3
>   %oparray_pop   1872   1   3
>   %oparray_pop   1755   1   3
>   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
>   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push Dictionary stack:
>   --dict:1149/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:70/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local
>   Current file position is 1

Is it possible to get any boolean value, or is there any way to identify whether the shell script executed correctly or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check if `$?.exitstatus` is 0.

```
>> %x{ls /etc/services}
=> "/etc/services\n"
>> $?.exitstatus
=> 0

>> %x{ls failfail}
ls: cannot access failfail: No such file or directory
=> ""
>> $?.exitstatus
=> 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides tokland's solution, you can also use `system`, if you don't need the return value of the command (but only if it worked correctly):

```
>> system 'ls /etc/services'
/etc/services
=> true
>> system 'ls /etc/failfail'
ls: cannot access /etc/failfail: No such file or directory
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

this should convert only PDF files into jpg. (the new files will have extension file.pdf.jpg)

```
ls -1 | xargs file | grep ': PDF document,' | sed 's/:.*//' | xargs -I % convert % %.jpg
```

or this will convert only pdf files into filename.jpg

```
ls -1 | xargs file | grep ': PDF document,' | sed 's/:.*//' | while read file; do b=`basename $file .pdf`; convert $file $b.jpg; done
```

Comment: thanks @jm666. I love the second one. It's perfect. And, one more thing, can you alter the second one as my wish. I would like to rename the file ($b.jpg) with filename with the base directory. An example, "/home/test/m.pdf" means i need the name of "jpg", "test_m.jpg". Please help me.